# how can I send view with parameters

Tags: android, android-studio, view, onclicklistener

I want to send `view` to another class with parameters

**for example :**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EventHandlerClass.startMediaPlayer(view, soundID);

            }
        });
```

you can see this line where i'm sending `View`

```
EventHandlerClass.startMediaPlayer(view, soundID);
```

Service Class

```
public static void startMediaPlayer(View view, Integer soundID){

    try {

        // Check if the sound id was set correctly
        if (soundID != null){

            // Check if the MediaPlayer maybe is in use
            // If so the MediaPlayer will be reset
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), soundID);
                mp.start();
            }

            // Create and start the MediaPlayer on the given sound id
        }
    } catch (Exception e){

        // Log error if process failed
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to start the MediaPlayer: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It only sends when you press the `button` , I want to send the offer but without pressing the `button` how?

Comment: call after creating your activity .

Comment: Are you sending By RecyclerVIew Adapter Class ?@haley

Comment: of course @Abhishekkumar

Comment: In what situation are you want to call that method . @jignesh Can you describe in brief

Comment: try to use Handler class for sending view.

Comment: @haley..  you have not posted code for the event when you want to call this method. In posted code You are adding click event on each item of recyclerview. You need to explain more in your post

Comment: edited now @SanjayMajoka

Comment: I want send 2 view button if sound not empty show button and hide another button

Comment: sorry my language is bad

Comment: You are calling that class by recyclerview Adapter but in what situation do you want to call that class by recyclerview Adapter class, itemView.setOnClick means you are calling EventHandlerClass class by when you tap on any reyclerRow. @haley

Comment: Are you trying to achive AutoPlay? when user sees the View it should AutoPlay? @haley

Comment: I want when click button start go to service class and check if sound enable hide button start and show button stop you can understand me ?

Comment: my quastion how send 2 view to service class